# QT Table Model Memory Usage

Tags: qt, memory, tablemodel, qvector

I have a general question on memory consumption. I have a program that uses a QAbstractTableModel storing data in a QVector. This is used to populate a Table View for an excel like grid. It is 18 columns and the data consists of general text strings.

When loading approximately 300000 rows, my application uses around 1.1GB of RAM.

Is this normal? If not, any suggestions for reducing memory usage. I do need to see the entire dataset. I can open an equivalent file in Excel and it uses 200MB, so I assume there must be a way to handle this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Read the data from the file when needed (and cache some extra rows for speed performance) and do not store everything in `QVector` (= ram). I assume you are unable to view 300000 rows at the same time (without scrolling).

Comment: Are all cells of your 'spreadsheet' populated or can you use a sparse storage scheme? It would also be useful to see the existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was considering using fetchmore, but after researching it appears that would only buy me a little bit of time as it would eventually fill up the vector. I looked into using QCache, but not sure if that's viable. I suppose I could try to code my own "window" of rows by trying to keep a subset of rows loaded.

Comment: G.M. I would have to send you the source code as I have several classes and a bit of code. If you want to compile and run it, I'd be glad to send it to you.